# Хочу создать новый проект, в начале хочу ввести npm init, но выводится ошибка

Tags: visual-studio-code

npm : Имя "npm" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сцен
ария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имен
строка:1 знак:1

- npm init
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], Comma
  ndNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

можете более менее подробно обьяснить что делать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит npm не установлен или не прописан в переменной окружения PATH. Это никак не связано с visual studio code.

Comment: 1. Установите [npm](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). 2. `npm --init` а не `npm init`